# Actualizar una aplicación en Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

les pido ayuda para poder actualizar una aplicación en Ubuntu 20.04.

La situación: tengo instalada la aplicación Mailspring 1.7.8 y me avisa que hay una nueva versión, la 1.8.0.
Descargo el paquete `.deb` pero cuando ejecuto `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install mailspring` me indica lo siguente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También ejecuté `sudo apt-get install mailspring` y obtuve el mismo resultado.

¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Entiendo que apt-get va a buscar la última versión que hay en el repositorio. Si querés instalar desde el archivo .deb tenés que usar otro comando.
Por lo que encontré deberías ejecutar `sudo dpkg -i package_file.deb`

Comment: También podés probar ejecutar primero `apt-get update`, eso va a actualizar las versiones de los paquetes disponibles, quizás ahí te reconozca la versión 1.8.0 para que la instales con `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install mailspring`

Comment: Excelente @Gonzalingui muchas gracias!
se actualizó 'Unpacking mailspring (1.8.0) over (1.7.8) ...'  
Usé el ´sudo dpkg -i ...´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero tienes que actualizar el listado de paquetes disponibles y sus versiones usando `sudo apt-get update`.

Si la versión 1.8.0 (o superior) está disponible, la vas a poder actualizar usando `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install mailspring` o más simple: `sudo apt-get upgrade mailspring`.

En cambio, si la actualización no está disponible en el repositorio o si quieres instalar el software desde el archivo que has descargado, deberías ejecutar este comando:

`sudo dpkg -i package_file.deb` donde package_file.deb se refiere al nombre del archivo descargado.